# fs.existsSync is not waiting for fs.readFile inside if

Tags: node.js, fs

```
if (fs.existsSync('tmp/cache.txt')) {
        fs.readFile("tmp/cache.txt", function (err, data) {
            if (data != "" || data != "[]") {
                jdata = JSON.parse(data);
                if (
                    jdata[jdata.length - 1].substring(4, 8) ==
                    new Date().getFullYear() + 543
                ) {
                    year = new Date().getFullYear() + 542;
                    console.log("yes this year");
                }
                jdata.forEach(function (value, i) {
                    if (
                        value.substring(4, 8) ==
                        new Date().getFullYear() + 543
                    ) {
                        countloveme--;
                    }
                });
                jdata.splice(countloveme);
            }
        });
    }
```

my code is running but

code is finished before fs.readFile inside ifelse have finish

i don't how to add await in fs.readFile or anyway to this code is working

Comment: It seems you're aware of the sync version of `exists` but not [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options), noting that it still might be a good idea to get a handle on general async programming.

Comment: `fs.readFile()` is non-blocking and asynchronous so your code does not wait for it to complete.  If synchronous code is OK in your application (e.g. it's NOT a server), then you can use `fs.readFileSync()`.  Otherwise, you need to learn how to write proper asynchronous code in nodejs and we'd need to see the surrounding code context before we could suggest a proper way to write this since the calling code will have to change too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments, it would be a better choice to use `fs,readFileSync`

And when you use `Array.forEach()` you are starting a new function that is running synchronously.

I've cleared your code maybe this can help you

```
if (fs.existsSync('tmp/cache.txt')) {

    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync("tmp/cache.txt");
        if (!data || data != "" || data != "[]")
            throw new Error('tmp/cache.txt file is empty');

        const jdata = JSON.parse(data);

        // More clear to use variables in the if elses
        const arg1 = jdata[jdata.length - 1].substring(4, 8)
        const arg2 = new Date().getFullYear() + 543;

        if (arg1 === arg2) {
            // You don't use this date anywhere?
            new Date().getFullYear() + 542;
            console.log("yes this year");
        }
        
        for (let dataChunk of jdata) {
            if (
                dataChunk.substring(4, 8) ==
                new Date().getFullYear() + 543
            ) {
                countloveme--;
            }
        }
        jdata.splice(countloveme);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }

}
```